# How to detect what dialect a written text comes from (given a parent language)

Tags: nlp

Ex. Suppose I have a Spanish text, and it has a lot of Colombian slang. How would I be able to detect that it is Colombian Spanish?

Comment: You'd have to train your model on text that's labeled "Columbian".

Comment: @duffymo makes sense, but I want something more than a binary classification. I want it to be able to look at any spanish text and be able to tell me which dialect it's from

Comment: Get tons of examples of Colombian Spanish and other variations of Spanish, and then train a multi-label classifier. If you want to solve the general problem as stated (for any language parent)... just the same procedure for every language. It's gonna be amazing.

Comment: never trained an NLP model before. I'm a beginner. @IgnatiusReilly what's the state of the art to get this done? My project is already written with Spacy for basic POS tags, can I use Spacy for this task?

Comment: @johnrabbit do you realize this is a project that could take many years, and labelers (money)... the kind of projects that would take years to companies like Google to complete?

Comment: i mean, I suppose, but can't I trivially have spacy or some other NLP framework just do POS tagging? i dont thinl that difference in dialects is grammatical
edit: some of it is, but with a language like spanish, I would guess that dialectal words would be enough to distinguish

Comment: Maybe, you could look at whether there're public databases with dialects of different languages. But it sounds to me a bit too much from the point of view of data. The framework is not the problem. The goal is.